# reading textfile returning empty variable in tensorflow

Tags: text, tensorflow, readfile

I have a text file which has 110 rows and 1024 columns of float values. I am trying to load the textfile and it doesnt read any thing.

```
filename = '300_faults.txt'
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([filename])
reader = tf.TextLineReader()
_,a = reader.read(filename_queue)
#x = np.loadtxt('300_faults.txt')  # working
#a = tf.constant(x,tf.float32)     # working

model = tf.initialize_all_variables()
with tf.Session() as session:
    session.run(model)
    print(session.run(tf.shape(a)))
```

printing the shape of the variable returns `[]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly - `tf.shape(a) == []` doesn't mean that variable is empty. All scalars and strings have shape `[]`.

https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/dims_types

May be you can check "rank" instead - it would be 0 for scalars and strings.
Other than that it looks like `string_input_producer` is a queue and it needs additional wiring to make ti work.

Please try this

```
filename = '300_faults.txt'
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([filename])
reader = tf.TextLineReader()
_,a = reader.read(filename_queue)
#x = np.loadtxt('300_faults.txt')  # working
#a = tf.constant(x,tf.float32)     # working

model = tf.initialize_all_variables()
with tf.Session() as session:
    session.run(model)

    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

    print(session.run(tf.shape(a)))

    print(session.run((a)))
    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)
```

Comment: But when i print the variable I can print only the first row. And if I access the variable ( for example print(session.run(a[1,1])) )it shows me error " Value Error: Index out of range using input dim 0; input has only 0 dims for 'stride_slice'

Comment: I think you need to parse the line. I mean if it's a string, you can't just access it as if it was an array (like you do in vanilla python). 
https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/reading_data
Check that "cvs files" part!